# one-to-many relationship foreign key count

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; } //PK

    public string emailAddress { get; set; }

    public List<Task> tasks { get; set; }

}
public class Task
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; } //PK 

    public string name { get; set; }

    //Navigation Properties
    public User user{ get; set; }

    public int userId { get; set; }

}
```

I've got two models above configured following the MSDN tutorial. So how can I properly get the number of tasks associated with a user?

I tried `context.users.Where(u => u.emailAddress == email).FirstOrDefaultAsync().tasks.count;` but it gives me a null pointer reference on the tasks object.
Then I tried `context.tasks.Where(o=>o.user.emailAddress==email).Count()` gives me correct number so it works

so I am wondering why the List is a null reference instead of a list with some elements in? thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following query:

```cs
var cnt = context.users
   .Where(u => u.emailAddress == email)
   .Select(u => u.tasks.Count())
   .FirstOrDefault();
```

You have to use LINQ extension `Count()` instead of `List.Count`

Comment: thanks for the help. I have one more question, I want to get the list itself, so I modified ur code to `context.users.Where(u => u.emailAddress == email).Select(u => u.tasks).FirstOrDefaultAsync()` to get the list itself, but actually, my Task class has another List<Category> member, but from the results, it's not picking up that nested list automatically, so how can I get around with it?

Comment: If you use `Select` - EF will not load related entities implicitly. You have to specify that. Anyway maybe you just need `Include` query for loading several levels?

Comment: thanks, I read that Eager loading concept and used `Include and  ThenInclude` it works

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using entity framework with Eager loading ([description](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/eager-loading-lazy-loading-and-explicit-loading-in-entity-framework/)). In that case you should call explicitly `Include()` method to load all user tasks. Example:

`await (context.users.Where(u => u.emailAddress == email).Include(u => u.Tasks).FirstOrDefaultAsync()).Tasks.Count();`

UPD: Not for the Production

Comment: Don't do that in production. Eager Load records to just count details is bad idea ever.